# Proximity Search?

Tags: 8, search, location

Is there a working solution for proximity search in Drupal 8 yet or is it a case of waiting for the modules to be redeveloped?

I want to help a user find the closest establishment to them within 100 miles and then e-mail the appropriate contact. I am using Leaflet, Address, Geofield, Geocoder and I can do most things with that combination. However, proximity search in views is not currently an option as far as i can tell.

If someone has found a way to make this work I would love to hear.